QField is loading some layers and missing others, "not packaged correctly."
I am trying to load my first QField project, using the QField cloud. I am downloading into the iOS phone app.
Some layers are loading and others are not. The layers loading are the basemap  and one point feature layer. Not loading are a polygon layer that I copied over and a new point and polygon layer that I made for digitizing within QField. I get an an error message shown below.
The first attempt was a OneDrive folder. From what I have gleaned from similar threads, I have moved everything to a folder with a short path with no spaces (by moving to a USB). Save Paths is set to Relative in project properties.
I am trying to "Convert currently open project to cloud project."  The local directory defaults to C:\Users... If I change it to the actual directory the Create button is greyed out. I used the default directory when the layers failed to load previously.
I have also tried importing the project as a local file from dropbox and I also have the missing files.
I have tried two projects. In the first project one of the now missing layers (made previously and copied over) did import but the new layers I made for the project did not.
Can someone explain how to fix this in layman's terms? I have followed the instructions in YouTube videos for creating and uploading the project and searched this site for answers.

